# Legends for scatter plots with NANs in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, scatter-plot

I am having problems creating legends for scatter plots with NAN values.

```
from numpy import *
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.pyplot import *

figure()
subplot(111)
h = scatter([NAN], [NAN], marker="o", facecolor="r", edgecolor="r", s=3)

legend([h], ["scatter"])

savefig("out.png")

close()
```

The code above fails with `ValueError` exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "legend.py", line 9, in <module>
    legend([h], ["scatter"])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.3.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 3381, in legend
    ret = gca().legend(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.3.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/axes.py", line 4778, in legend
    self.legend_ = mlegend.Legend(self, handles, labels, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.3.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/legend.py", line 366, in __init__
    self._init_legend_box(handles, labels)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.3.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/legend.py", line 630, in _init_legend_box
    handlebox)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.3.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/legend_handler.py", line 103, in __call__
    handlebox.get_transform())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.3.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/legend_handler.py", line 325, in create_artists
    width, height, fontsize)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.3.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/legend_handler.py", line 282, in get_sizes
    size_max = max(orig_handle.get_sizes()) * legend.markerscale ** 2
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
```

What is strange is that the exception is thrown only if I pass a one-element NAN list to `scatter()`. The result is as expected with empty lists and longer than 1 lists of NANs. The result is the same if I use numpy arrays instead of lists. Is there an explanation to this?

I am using `matplotlib` version `1.3.1`.

Comment: I find this intriguing as well but may I ask why you need to plot a scatter graph of [NaN], [NaN]?

Comment: I create hundreds of plots in a loop, each with data for a different 1-hour interval. It might happen that for some interval there is only one data point and, for some reason, is not a correct measurement. So I'm not trying to explicitly plot a single (NAN, NAN) point, but it would be great if `scatter` didn't throw an error in such case

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround: try plotting the legend with a proxy artist. This breaks the automatic entry but at least it seems to do what you need...

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D

h = plt.scatter([np.nan], [np.nan], marker="o", facecolor="r", edgecolor="r", s=3)
proxy = [Line2D(range(1), range(1), color="white", marker='o', markerfacecolor="red")]

plt.legend(proxy, ["scatter"])
plt.show()
```

Comment: I think this is slightly more complex. If I had the following data: `x = [5, NAN, 7, NAN]; y = [8, 9, NAN, NAN]`, then `scatter(x, y, ...)` would plot one point: `(5, 8)`. So masking should check if any of `x` and `y` coordinates is NAN. This solution adds unnecessary complexity to the code. `scatter` seems to be handling NANs correctly (in most cases). I was wondering if there is a reason why one-element NAN lists are treated this way

Comment: I haven't anywhere found an information that NANs can be passed to `scatter`. Maybe it's just a coincidence that it works fine for non-one element lists

Comment: NaN is a float ( try `print(type(np.nan))` ) which is why it should work. Also, I realized that my answer was absolute codswallop and didn't solve anything. I've edited it to propose you another workaround that still doesn't answer the question as *why* this is happening

Comment: Thanks, this looks like a nice workaround. I've identified the source of the problem, I will explain in a separate post

Answer (score 0):

OK I've found the source of the problem.

The error appears when the two conditions are met while calling `scatter`:

1. The length of `s=` (marker size) is equal to the data length
2. No points are plotted, i. e. for each `index`, `x[index]` or `y[index]` is NAN or INFINITY

So, for example, this will also fail:

```
scatter([NAN, 2], [3, NAN], marker="o", s=[3, 4])
```

The problem lies in line 3602 of `axes/_axes.py` (in `scatter` function):

```
        x, y, s, c = cbook.delete_masked_points(x, y, s, c)
```

(`x` and `y` are data points, `s` -- marker sizes, `c` -- colors).

The [`delete_masked_points`](http://matplotlib.org/api/cbook_api.html#matplotlib.cbook.delete_masked_points) documentation says:

> Find all masked and/or non-finite points in a set of arguments, and return the arguments with only the unmasked points remaining.
>
> (...)
>
> Any argument with a length differing from that of the first argument (...) will be passed through unchanged.

So, if the two conditions mentioned earlier are met, `s` becomes an empty array. Later, in the `legend` function call, `size_max` can't be calculated.

The solution would be to do sth like:

```
        s_copy = s
        x, y, s, c = cbook.delete_masked_points(x, y, s, c)
        if len(s) == 0:
            s = s_copy
```

I will send a message to matplotlib-users

Thanks @7hibault for your help!

Comment: Great job on identifying the source of the problem. I've raised an issue on Github here https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/4365 !

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the problem still exists even though an issue was raised on GitHub. It may not throw an error, but the correct symbol does not appear in the legend.

Another thing that works well is to use:

```
    plt.plot(x, y, c=color, marker=marker_style, linestyle='None', label=label_name)
```

The symbol for the np.nan data point now shows up in the legend using 'plot' instead of 'scatter'.